# Are there any clones/alternatives for running a Stack Exchange style Q&A site?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, clone

Since the source code for this site isn't available for purchase or external use, I'm looking for software that can run a Q&A environment similar to Stack Exchange. Are there any such pieces of software available?

Answer (score 962):

[Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams), a hosted solution, is available for use. In the past there was an enterprise version of Stack Overflow, but this is now deprecated.

But if that does not meet your needs, there are several third-party tools that try to clone at least some of the functionality here.

**Most active that look like the best bets**

***Open source***

- **[ASKBOT](http://askbot.org/en/questions/)**: Python/Django. [Hosting](http://askbot.com), [code](http://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel), [docs](http://askbot.org/doc/index.html), [import](http://askbot.org/doc/import-data.html). GPLv3
- **[Biostars](https://github.com/ialbert/biostar-central)**: [Demo](https://biostars.org). Python, Django. MIT license
- **[Discourse](https://discourse.org)**: [Demo](https://try.discourse.org). Ruby on Rails, GPLv2 license
- **[Mamute](http://www.mamute.org/)**: [Demo 1](http://demo.mamute.org/), [Demo 2](http://meta.mamute.org/) (June 11, 2017: Demo sites do not work). Java. Customizable. Apache 2 license
- **[Codidact/QPixel](https://codidact.com)**: Ruby on Rails. [GitHub](https://github.com/codidact/qpixel). AGPL.
- **[Question2Answer](http://www.question2answer.org/)**: [Demo](http://www.question2answer.org/qa/). PHP, MySQL. [Fairly active](https://github.com/q2a/question2answer). GPLv2+
- **[Scoold](https://scoold.com/)**: [Demo](https://live.scoold.com/), Java, active since Jan. 2017, Apache 2 license
- **[Talkyard](https://www.talkyard.io)**: [Demo](https://www.talkyard.io/forum/latest). React.js, Scala. Also has open-ended discussions & chat. [Hosting](https://www.talkyard.io/pricing), [code](https://github.com/debiki/talkyard), [installation](https://github.com/debiki/talkyard-prod-one). AGPL.
- **[TopAnswers](https://topanswers.xyz/)**: PHP. [GitHub](https://github.com/topanswers/topanswers). AGPL.
- **[Vanilla Forums](https://vanillaforums.com/en/features/qna/)**: [Demo](https://open.vanillaforums.com/discussions/unanswered). PHP, MySQL. Forums with [Q&A config option](http://docs.vanillaforums.com/help/addons/qna/). [Active](https://github.com/vanilla/vanilla) and has [Commercial and Open Source](https://vanillaforums.com/en/software/) plans. GPLv2

***Not open source***

- **[AllAnswered](https://www.allanswered.com)**: Django. Include Q&A in its knowledge management system. Not Free.
- **[AnswerHub](http://www.dzonesoftware.com/products/answerhub-question-answer-software)**: Java. [Live site](http://community.dzonesoftware.com/). Enterprise Q&A by the people who created [OSQA](http://www.dzonesoftware.com/products/open-source-question-answer-software). Not free.
- **[Confluence Questions](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/questions)**: Java. Enterprise Q&A developed and supported by [Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/). Not free.
- **[Haydle](http://haydle.com/)**: SaaS, free 30 day trial.  Haydle is focused on being a private, internal Q&A system.
- **[Q&A](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/qa-wordpress-questions-and-answers-plugin/)**: [<s>Live Site</s>](http://wpmu.org/questions/). WordPress Plugin. Actively developed by a company that looks reliable. No longer free; $19 to download (with no membership)
- **[Quandora](http://www.quandora.com)**
- **[SabaiDiscuss](http://sabaidiscuss.com/)**: commercial WordPress Plugin
- **[Tribe](https://tribe.so)**: SaaS, freemium plan.  Tribe allows you to build your own social app (including internal or external Q&A sites).
- **[Unity Answers](https://answers.unity.com)**: Allowed topics are the Unity editor and C# (the site is free and in English)

**Ones that look sort of finished**

- **[shapado](https://github.com/ricodigo/shapado)**: Ruby, mongomapper and MongoDB. AGPLv3. Website unreachable, Last commit in 2012.
- **[OSQA](https://github.com/dzone/osqa)**: Django. GPLv3. Last commit in 2015. [AnswerHub](http://dzonesoftware.com/) has replaced OSQA as DZone's primary Q&A solution.
- **[openoverflow](https://github.com/nsanta/openoverflow)**: Ruby, PostgreSQL, Haml. MIT license. No example site, and I can't find anyone using this one. Not a lot of recent activity; last code commit, May 2009.
- **[phpancake](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpancake/)**: PHP, Zend framework, MySQL. [Live site](http://phpancake.sourceforge.net/). MIT license. Last activity Jan 2013. Renders very poorly in some browsers; the live site states "I am aware of this site not working properly. I am working on it!".
- **[Rootbuzz](https://www.rootbuzz.com/)**: (site down) Django, hosting, actively developed, non-free
- **[Programlama](https://programlama.tk)**: Python, flask (In Turkish)
- **[cahoots](http://cahoots.sourceforge.net/)**: PHP, MySQL. GPL, MIT license. Officially inactive; demo site offline; last update Aug 2010.
- **[Coordino](http://coordino.com/)**: PHP, MySQL. MIT license. [feature tour](http://coordino.com/tour); last commit in 2015.
- **[Qwench](https://github.com/anantgarg/Qwench)**: PHP. [Example site](http://anantgarg.com/qwench) (currently offline). [Almost no activity since 2009](https://github.com/anantgarg/Qwench/commits/master).
- **[soclone](https://code.google.com/p/soclone/)**: Django framework. MIT license. Seems to have [gone stale in Nov 2008](https://code.google.com/p/soclone/source/list) (and only started on Google Code at the end of Oct 2008).
- **[Solace](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/solace)**: Inactive; last commit in 2010.
- **[PaizaQA](https://github.com/gi-no/paizaqa)**: [Demo](http://paizaqa.herokuapp.com), MEAN (MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, and Node.js), Not active, MIT license
- **[Kliqqi](https://github.com/Kliqqi-CMS/Kliqqi-CMS/)**: PHP, MySQL. Different look, hosting available. Not active, CC-BY 3.0 license
- **[stacked](https://code.google.com/p/stacked/)**: ASP.NET, Ra-Ajax, ActiveRecord ORM. GPLv3.
- **[Arrayshift](http://drupal.org/project/arrayshift)** Drupal plugin GPLv2, last commit in 2016.
- **[Kunjika](https://github.com/Nalanda-Labs/Kunjika)**: Rust, Actix, Sevlte and Postgres. GNU GPLv3 or later.

**Others that seem to be work in progress**

- **[Asking](https://github.com/Bivee/asking)**: Perl, Mojolicious. Perl License (Artistic). Little documentation at this point. GitHub repository README.md in Portuguese.
- **[FortyTwo](https://github.com/mcaprari/fortytwo/)**: Python, Django, CouchDB. [Example site](http://couch.caprazzi.net/fortytwo/_design/fortytwo/index.html) *link leads to a 404*. Unknown license. Little information. [Last commit in January 2011]
- **[kerjakelompok](https://github.com/fuadmuhammad/kerjakelompok/)**: No example site. Unknown license. Little info.
- **[SmartR](https://github.com/dkd/smartr/)**: No example site. MIT License. Little info.
- <s>**[Stack Underflow](https://github.com/ripper234/Stack-Underflow/)**: C#. No example site. License is "do whatever you want with it" (I haven't defined a formal license yet). Written as a learning project.</s> No longer supported.
- **[T002_rails-overflow](https://github.com/membrain/T002_rails-overflow/)**: Ruby on Rails. No example site. Unknown license. Little info. Apache license.
- <s>**[CNPROG](https://github.com/cnprog/CNPROG)**: Python/Django.</s> Project officially closed. Was used as base by OSQA & Askbot.
- **[QARoR](http://github.com/mateuszdw/qaror)** - open source questions & answers platform for Ruby on Rails. Here is the [demo](http://qaror.herokuapp.com) and source on [GitHub](http://github.com/mateuszdw/qaror). Released under MIT License.
- **[Veaos](https://github.com/veaos/veaos)**: MERN (MongoDB, Express, React and Node.js)

### Sorted by language

**PHP**

- **[Arrayshift](http://drupal.org/project/arrayshift)**
- **[cahoots](http://cahoots.sourceforge.net/)**
- **[Coordino](http://coordino.com/)**
- **[Kliqqi](https://github.com/Kliqqi-CMS/Kliqqi-CMS/)**
- **[LampCMS](http://www.lampcms.com)**
- **[phpancake](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpancake/)**
- **[Q&A](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/qa-wordpress-questions-and-answers-plugin/)** (Is a WordPress Plugin)
- **[Question2Answer](http://www.question2answer.org/)**
- **[TopAnswers](https://topanswers.xyz/)**
- **[Vanilla Forums](https://vanillaforums.com/en/features/qna/)**

**Perl**

- **[Asking](https://github.com/Bivee/asking)**

**Python**

- **[ASKBOT](http://askbot.org/en/questions/)**
- **[Biostars](https://github.com/ialbert/biostar-central)**
- **[FortyTwo](https://github.com/mcaprari/fortytwo/)**
- **[Django-knowledge](https://github.com/zapier/django-knowledge)**
- **[OSQA](https://github.com/OSQA/osqa/)** ([merged](http://dzonesoftware.com/qa/questions/40767/a-much-needed-upgrade-for-metaosqanet.html) to AnswerHub)
- **[soclone](https://code.google.com/p/soclone/)**
- **<s>[Rootbuzz](https://www.rootbuzz.com/)</s>** (site down, last tweet dates back to 2013)
- **<s>[Programlama](https://programlama.tk)</s>** (site down)

**Ruby**

- **[openoverflow](https://github.com/nsanta/openoverflow)** (last commit in 2009)
- **[T002_rails-overflow](https://github.com/membrain/T002_rails-overflow/)** (last commit in 2009)
- <s>**[SmartR](https://github.com/dkd/smartr/)**</s> Creator announced it is deprecated.
- **[QARoR](http://github.com/mateuszdw/qaror)** (barely any progress)
- **[Discourse](https://discourse.org)** (active, primarily a discussion forum)
- **[Codidact/QPixel](https://codidact.com)**

**Rust**

- **[kunjika](https://github.com/Nalanda-Labs/Kunjika)**

**Java**

- **[AnswerHub](http://dzonesoftware.com/)**
- **[Confluence Questions](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/questions)**
- **[Mamute](http://www.mamute.org/)**
- **[Scoold](https://live.scoold.com/)**

**Scala**

- **[Talkyard](https://www.talkyard.io)**

**ASP.NET**

- **[stacked](https://code.google.com/p/stacked/)**
- <s>**[Stack Underflow](https://github.com/ripper234/Stack-Underflow/)**</s> No longer supported.
- **[VolatileRead](http://volatileread.com/)**

**MEAN/MERN (MongoDB, Express, Angular/React, and Node.js)**

- **[PaizaQA](https://github.com/gi-no/paizaqa)**
- **[Veaos](https://github.com/veaos/veaos)**

*Did I miss any? Disagree? Please add a comment or update this answer.*

Comment: Not sure where this comment belongs, but I recently deployed and customized Question2Answer in 15 minutes, whereas OSQA took hours and still isn't working right. FWIW!

Comment: Do all these look like StackExchange sites on purpose?!

Comment: I noticed how **Java** was the only language without an entry. According to http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109004/160875 Qato is written in Java. (The original question asked for web apps inspired by the StackExchange system, but didn't specify open source. Some of the other answers mention non-open source implementations of SE, but I had my eye on that *None known* spot under "Java"!)

Comment: After getting tired of OSQA and its django dependencies, I installed question2answer and worked great so far: pretty complete, lots of plugins.

Comment: I may be building a stackoverflow clone in the near future - anyone know pros and cons of building it myself from scratch vs. using something like Q&A (the WordPress plugin)?

Comment: @YatharthROCK I don't know how that text came to be, but the project is abandoned anyway.

Comment: Do any of these clone SE's excellent chat? For my Q&A needs, I'm OK with using the SE family, but that chat is fantastic and I'd love to see it (or something like it) start replacing IRC.

Comment: @Evgeny Thanks a lot for the list. Any idea which Q&A system has most features?

Comment: formally or formerly Qato?

Comment: askoverflow.com is also a clone, I suppose.

Comment: @Evgeny: There is one but not exactly a Stackoverflow type instead it's a Forum type with lots of Stackoverflow Features like badges and vote up and down and etc.  
**http://www.mvcforum.com/**

Comment: RootBuzz is giving me an SSL error, and their Twitter account seems to be linking to a bunch of spammy junk.  Maybe they're dead?

Comment: @Evgeny Add nukson.com http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199314/is-nukson-com-part-of-stackexchange-sites#199315

Comment: shapado only receives translation updates for over a year now, https://gitorious.org/shapado/shapado/activities. Likewise, OSQA also isn't very active with a mere 5 commits this year (https://github.com/dzone/osqa/commits/master).

Comment: Atlassian now offers a Q&A add-on for Confluence - Confluence Questions. Check it out: https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/questions

Comment: Not a clone but worth the mention. I'm building a Q&A (will also work as a forum or social sharing if needed) app in Python (Flask + Gevent + MongoDB) which will implement features seen here (like chat, moderation etc..) and more. It will also have an easy "wizard" installation unlike existing Python solutions. Atm it's still very messy and still not worth testing, but I'm working on it. Watch the progress on here: https://github.com/yakamooz/yakamooz

Comment: @disgruntledgoat Why remove [QARoR](https://github.com/mateuszdw/qaror/)?

Comment: @Adam although there is a section for "half finished clones" that one didn't look very developed at all. Also it looks like the person who added it is the developer; I thought that would count as spam. If others think the project is fine, go ahead and put it back.

Comment: I realise this is an old thread. But we have an ASP.NET MVC project which has similar features to SO. See here http://www.mvcforum.com

Comment: found one today: [Stack Overfluw](http://www.stackoverfluw.com/)

Comment: Hello, Im the QARoR developer and put it into this topic. What can i say more about development... StartX Stanford already use QARoR, so its not that bad right? There are few apps here which "didn't look very developed at all" for example T002_rails-overflow. DisgruntledGoat, give people a proper choice. @AdamDavis if you think its interesting app, do us a favor and put it back. Thank you!

Comment: Existing solutions aren't performant at all if you need many users...

Comment: @user965091 Kunjika will perform even with 100000 users. With a very small virtual server it could handle 100 req/second. Disclaimer: I am developer of Kunjika.

Comment: @user902384 i would use Kunjika but how i can optimise for handling 300 req/second

Comment: @user965091 I have not benchmarked for more than 100req/sec but I think Kunjika should be able to handle that with a decent machine. The reason is the interaction between database and app server is minimal because couchbase is document store and it can handle lots of simultaneous connections easily.

Comment: @user965091 If you want to optimize then one optimization which is not done yet is caching. Couchbase also provides memcached buckets so putting in caching is easy.

Comment: Saying AnswerHub is a clone of Stack Exchange is basically saying that any Q&A site with quality is a clone. Following that logic let's add [Quora](http://www.quora.com) as a clone!

Comment: @Evgeny Thanks for an awesome answer! I'm trying to look for the ones that has an API using which I can include a similar Q&A inside my mobile app. I am still to find an open source one. Do you know one by any chance ?

Comment: [I found another.](http://www.aiqus.com/forum/questions/13886/i-want-to-make-a-learning-ai-but-what-should-it-learn)

Comment: This answer needs an overhaul. Plenty of things are now stale, or not in active development.

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/xameeramir/StackOverflowClone then. Completely free Stackoverflow clone

Comment: Area all of these open sourced? My skill set is particularly more advanced in ASP.net. I like Volatile Read, but it does not appear to be open sourced.

Comment: Rootbuzz looks dead

Comment: hello - well great thread - but i see it like other: This answer really needs an overhaul. Plenty of things are now stale, or not in active development. –

Comment: While I didn't get to try any others, Question2answer worked out quite well for me. It allows you to customize CSS and gives you a lot of control to inject your own html across the site. You also have access to the php files so you can always make your own modifications as needed but lucky I didn't need to.

Comment: @KRyan Look at Florian Margaine's [Miaou](https://miaou.dystroy.org/static/intro.html) chat, which was inspired by SO chat...is open source...and has been actively maintained for many years.

Comment: Hi, does any of these have access to language changes?

Comment: Askbot maintainer is struggling in keeping it up-to-date. [The documentation link is broken](https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel/issues/779), the project is [still using Python 2 and Django 1.8](https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel/issues/772), and [project maintenance status was challenged](https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel/issues/758). Given that this is used by big projects like Fedora, I really don’t want to see it go away.

Comment: I developed Kunjika which I discontinued. Now I am working on another QA which you can find at https://github.com/Nalanda-Labs/arth. It is still under active development and not ready for use.

Comment: Discourse is not a Q&A framework, it's forum. you should remove it from the list.

Answer (score 89):

I am currently following [Codidact](https://codidact.org/) with some interest.

Codidact is a work in progress and fairly new, but describes itself as:

> A community-controlled, open-source Q&A platform.

---

**Further Information:**

- [Codidact Blog](https://meta.codidact.com/categories/30)
- [Codidact Wiki](https://github.com/codidact/docs/wiki) on GitHub
- [Codidact.org](https://codidact.org/) website
- [Codidact on GitHub](https://github.com/codidact)
- [Codidact's Network of Sites](https://codidact.com)

Comment: I'm a bit afraid about ASP as core technology... but ok, let it be

Comment: @Arenim as I understand, that's only an interim measure.

Comment: there is nothing more permanent than temporary =) Anyway I hope it will be good at their side =))

Comment: @Arenim, not ASP, but rather [ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/): "a free and open-source web framework, and higher performance than ASP.NET, developed by Microsoft and the community". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Core. And BTW, it's cross-platform :)

Comment: I joined recently. It seems they are going with what their key developers/contributors are experienced in. I have experience in some of the [tech stack](https://github.com/codidact/docs/wiki/Technology-Stack) they are using, so I plan to consider contributing in the future.

Comment: Regarding the above old comments here, Codidact originally started as an C# ASP.NET project, but since they didn't have enough devs familiar with that platform, it was switched to Ruby on Rails using an existing code base, to launch faster, which it still runs on today. It was released in spring 2020 and is a fairly mature site by now.

Comment: It's also the website where Monica went. So I have a feeling (and 0 proof) that significant chuck of original users on Codidact are former SO/SE users.

Comment: Some important differences between working on SE and Codidact: 1. In Codidact you can't see the post views. 2. In Codidact you don't have badges.

Answer (score 3):

[Splunk Answers](https://answers.splunk.com/) appears to be running some sort of Stack Overflow clone.

The logo in the bottom-right corner says "Powered by Khoros" but I have been unable to locate which product exactly they are using. The marketing materials I have looked at so far seem inconclusive, but I'm guessing it's [Khoros Atlas.](https://community.khoros.com/)

As you can tell from a few minutes on the site, the software by itself does not work very well if the user base is not taught how to curate. In the absence of a culture to engage with new answers and upvote good content, and downvote incorrect, off-topic, or unhelpful posts, it's just another digital landfill.

Comment: @Martin I really didn't expect a bounty for this; thank you!