# Should this Stack Overflow format be used for other topics?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> "The many are smarter than the few and collective wisdom can shape economies, societies, and nations."  J. Surowiecki

Could this Stack Overflow format be used in other areas and topics?  Be it anything from engineering, to cooking,  to travelling?  I know there is Wikipedia but perhaps this Stack Overflow format can take it all that much further.

Comment: Like ponies?  I someone who would like that allot...

Comment: Deep thoughts by TheTXI

Comment: Because I refuse to be shackled by the pretentious text limitations of Twitter!

Comment: ehsanul put this similar question out yesterday: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12010/adapting-the-so-engine-to-other-domains-not-related-to-computers/12035

Comment: "The many are smarter than the few" and "collective wisdom" are catch-phrases and fortune-cookie philosophies that were perpetrated by books such as "Wisdom of Crowds" despite ample contrary evidence. When he says that they "shape economies" he's deliberately misleading you to believe that the 'wisdom' of the crowd shaped the economy, rather than the 'will', the 'whims' or the 'waffling' of the crowd. Economies, societies and nations are shaped by the people in them. A fact which does not bestow ANY sort of intelligence on any of the individuals within them.

Comment: There are many crowded internet forums, (expertsexchange anyone?) that do not contain much wisdom. The crowd dynamics within them often turn cruel and unhelpful.

Comment: Sorry about that tirade. I know it's off topic, I just wasn't a fan of that book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the intent of [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/), to allow you to transport the engine to whatever topics you would like. Additionally, to this point Jeff & co. have expanded to 2 additional topics, plus this meta discussion site; so it's not outside the realm of possibilities that they could choose more topics to serve themselves.

Comment: I checked out the stackexchange. Interesting.  I know it says that buyers of the technology will be able to "override style sheets, choose color schemes, and provide your own logo," but I am wondering if users can go beyong that and add or delete actual controls and features?  Also perhaps be able to make money for ourselves as well? Do you know anything about it?

Comment: Um, if buyers weren't allowed to make money for themselves, there would be no market.

Comment: ** *facepalm* **

Comment: Agreed, unless a company was just renting it to help with production or communication within themselves.  I guess I am really interested in how much control we would have over the functionality itself.

Comment: True, internal use is probably one of their targets. There's money to be had there.