# Is Stack Overflow's code downloadable or free to use?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, source-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the Stack Overflow source code available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14656/is-the-stack-overflow-source-code-available)

Is the script running Stack Overflow downloadable? Are there similar scripts available?
I would like to know how Stack Overflow was structured; its function and design are pretty  straightforward. I would like to know about approaches to achieving the site's functions.

PS: Is `www.squarepolygon.com` related to Stack Overflow? I thought that if it was related to Stack Overflow, it would have a link in the footer. I just want to confirm.

Comment: Hmm... asking about alternatives makes it just one bit not-so meta.

Comment: see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14656/the-stackoverflow-source-code

Comment: Dupe of [Will Stack Overflow's engine be open-sourced?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35/will-stack-overflows-engine-be-open-sourced) and [Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/48962#48962)

Comment: That's one meaning of "script" I was not aware of.

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not open source or anything.
They do offer a [program](https://stackexchange.com/) where you can have your own SO-like site hosted, at a cost of course.

Answer (score 5):

Stack Overflow itself is not open-source. You can buy its service at stackexchange.com.

There are some Stack Overflow clones:

- http://code.google.com/p/cnprog/
- http://code.google.com/p/soclone/