# Etiquette for questions whose answer is stale

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with obsolete answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11705/how-to-deal-with-obsolete-answers)

As StackOverflow has gotten older and the recommended way of doing things has evolved over time. [A feature was proposed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105629/mark-question-or-answers-as-stale) earlier, but it sounds complicated. Without a feature to support marking something as stale, what is the etiquette for handling such an answer? Leaving a comment on the answer that it's no longer up to date? Providing an alternate answer that calls out that something has changed?

Answer (score 0):

I think the better Idea would be to have a tag associated by the moderator or subject matter expert to that question which calls something like obsolete answer or stale-answer or something like that. We already have these tags like **status-by-design**, **status-completed**, **status-declined**, that are setup by moderators only/ May be the user who has maximum reps about that topic can set that flag.