# Why was this question deleted twice?

Tags: bug, deleted-questions

The question [Will Stack Overflow's engine be (someday, or ever) open sourced?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35/278659) was recently bumped to the top of the homepage. Glancing idly at the [revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/35/revisions), I noticed the following peculiarity:

[image: screenshot of double deletion]

Wait what? The question had already been deleted, but the Community bot somehow felt the need to delete it again? How can that happen?

**What's going on there?**

Comment: There is an event in the timeline for the second deletion: [help post localization backfill](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/35/timeline#history_fa8f85f5-710b-492a-b662-78f3b64fe935)

Comment: Guess Jeff messed directly with the database for some reason, making a mess.

Comment: To close-voters: it might not be exactly the same bug, since Jeff Atwood was the OP of one post and not the other (i.e. maybe "OP then Community" is a different bug from "mod then Community"). Also, why are we closing the older question as a duplicate of the newer dupe raising the same issue?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Given the close time proximity of these deletions and animuson's comment on the other issue, it seems like the same bug.

Comment: How it's [supposed to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/282094) work.