# What does the "help post localization backfill" automatic deletion reason mean?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, community-user

I noticed [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/sync-meta-user-accounts-daily-with-other-family-sites) (10k-only) that was apparently deleted by Community more than five years after it was originally deleted, but no events (neither undeletion nor anything else) have occurred since the post was first deleted.

The revision history shows two consecutive "post deleted" events: one in July 2009, and the other in December 2014:

[image: Post Deleted by Community, then Post Deleted by Jeff Atwood]

Interestingly, the deletion banner on the question itself only later shows the Community user's later deletion:

[image: deleted by Community]

I checked the post's [timeline](/posts/2/timeline), where the reason for the Community user deleting a post is usually listed if it wasn't as a result of the Roomba (e.g. was a negatively-scored post when the user's account was deleted, the user was destroyed, etc.). However, the relevant timeline entry lists some cryptic text, which I searched for and couldn't find the meaning of:

[image: help post localization backfill]

What does "help post localization backfill" mean, and why is there this extra "post deleted" event?

Comment: Interesting. It appears to have been some sort of mistake. 136 posts were deleted with that reason within the span of 2 days, but all of them were undeleted shortly after minus the ones that were already deleted prior. None of them seem to be particularly related to each other, either, and they occurred on both questions and answers.

Comment: @animuson Mind linking me to a timeline of an example post that was later undeleted?

Comment: Here's a random answer that was hit by it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/2599/timeline

Comment: @animuson Thanks. Mind pinging a dev to see what happened here?

Comment: If someone sees it and knows what happened, they might answer, but pinging people over a weird one-off issue that happened 5 years ago? That doesn't sound productive. I'd bet very few if any even remember.

Comment: @SonictheBracketedHedgehog well it has actually been asked before; just not by you. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328417/why-was-this-question-deleted-twice (not sure in which direction the closure should be...)

Comment: Why are we closing the older question as a dupe of the newer one? I know dupe direction is based on quality not age, but I don't see any major difference in quality here since we're both raising similar ([but maybe not the same!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328417/why-was-this-question-deleted-twice#comment1076111_328417)) bugs.

Comment: @Randal'Thor This one has more information including what it looks like in the timeline.

Comment: @Randal'Thor  It doesn't matter about the age of the post, if a question is newer but has better answers, the question which should be left opened is the newer one. However, I don't see any answers here, no.... none and I see only 4 upvotes for this question whereas the older one has 13 upvotes and no downvotes. -1 from me

Comment: @Mari-LouA If both questions have no answers, it's more about how much research each question has shown. This one shows more research than the other one, including a screenshot of the deletion "comment" left behind by the system in the timeline; the other one doesn't show as much research.

Comment: I could counter argue it's about how much consensus a post receives, and who was first. P.S You were the one who first voted close Rand al'Thor's question as a duplicate of this one. The type of behaviour some Brits might say ["not cricket"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/not-cricket)